# Match block inside block with pcre

Tags: php, regex, pcre

In [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/7pauyx/1), I'm trying to get the contents of each block:

```
{% block works %}
    This works
{% endblock %}

{% block main_block %}
    {% block sub_block %}
        Does not work
    {% endblock %} #ends here
    This is not covered
{% endblock %}
```

It works right if a block has no blocks inside, but, in the second block (main_block) it fails to match all of its content because one block is found inside.

I need a regex pattern that captures both main_block and sub_block blocks, without ending on the first {% endblock %} tag.

Right now, my expression looks like this: `\{\%\s*block\s?([a-z0-9\_]*?)\s?\%\}(.*?)(?>(?:{\%\s*block\s?([a-z0-9\_]*?)\s?\%\}|(?R))*\{\%\s?endblock\s?\1?\s?\%\}\is`

EDIT: my question was marked as duplicate, but I don’t think it has to do with that problem, mine is in a different scenario where blocks could be inside of blocks indefinitely.

Comment: You can't capture each block content using regex alone. But you can first validate format then go through a PHP process. https://regex101.com/r/7pauyx/2

Comment: @KenWhite sample data is in the beggining, edited the question and added the regex. Thank you and sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: Take a look at the dupe post. You'll have to implement something similar

Comment: @hjpotter92 current dupe doesn't have a solution to this question even indirectly and Java RegEx unlike PCRE doesn't support recursions.

Comment: Variant: [`{%\s*block\s?(\w+)\s*%}((?>[^}{]*(?R)?)*){%\s?endblock\s?%}`](https://regex101.com/r/7pauyx/3)

Comment: @bobblebubble but this won't match the very inner block, just the two external ones. I want to match all 3 blocks in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Regex Used: `'/(\ *){%\sblock.*\s%}((?:.*|\n)*?)\1{%\sendblock.*\s%}/'`

For this to work, it does assume that the blocks are properly formatted, but if they are formatted correctly, this will work in most cases (it uses the spaces before each block to determine whether the tags match or not).

Try this out for size:

```
<?php

function getBlockText($blockText)
{
    $regex = '/(\ *){%\sblock.*\s%}((?:.*|\n)*?)\1{%\sendblock.*\s%}/';
    $recursedMatches= [];
    preg_match_all($regex, $blockText, $matches);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[2]); $i++) {
        if(preg_match($regex, $matches[2][$i])){
            array_push($recursedMatches, getBlockText($matches[2][$i]));
        } else {
            array_push($recursedMatches, $matches[2][$i]);
        }
    }

    return $recursedMatches;
}


$str = '{% block works %}
    This works
{% endblock %}

{% block main_block %}
    {% block sub_block %}
        Does not work
    {% endblock %} #ends here
    This is not covered
    {% block sub_block %}
        Does not work
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}';

print_r(getBlockText($str));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    This works

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        Does not work

            [1] => 
        Does not work

        )

)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. The output should return "This is not covered" as a content for main_block. Everything that is not a block is considered content. For that matter, "#ends here" should've also been returned (though I've used it to emphasize that the regex ended there and not on the last {% endblock %}.